# SAP SLT Error: Errors in setting connections

Tags: db2, hana, slt

At the end of the dialog for creating a new SLT configuration we get the message: Errors in setting connections - no further information.

The source system is Ubuntu 14.04 with DB2 the target System is SLES 12.

Does anybody know if/where there a log entries or how else to debug the issue?

[image: Error Message at end of configuration: "Errors in setting connections"]

Hint: in the target System HANA nothing is created - neither the user and schema neither the configuration tables.
(According to the documentation a use with the same name as the schema is created)

We use the system user as administrative user creating the initial connection to HANA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by selecting **DB6 instead of DB2** as Database - within create new configuration of transaction LTRC.

Also make sure to use the correct **tablespace** name! The default tablespace on DB2 is **USERSPACE1**